# Using a declared variable to divide by number in PythonWin

Tags: python

I declared my variables but as with other intro programming languages, I have been able to do simple division once the variable is set. I can see Python is a bit different. 
Here's what I have:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#set workspace, allow overwrites
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/../PoliceData.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#create variables
patrolZone = "C:/Users/.../PatrolZones"
graffitiIncidents = "C:/Users/.../GraffitiIncidents"
incidentField = "INCIDENTS"
priorityField = "PRIORITY"
area = "SHAPE_area"
nameField = "NAME"
areaSQMI = area/2589988.11
```

The SHAPE_area is a field within an attribute table. I realize I can't do this because of the traceback error? I am just trying to change sq m to sq mi.

Comment: Are you trying to divide a `string` by a `float`?

Comment: yes @beercodebeer. This is what I had tried: areaSQMI = float(area)/2589988.11
ValueError: could not convert string to float: SHAPE_area. Since I am calling on a field within the attribute table, how differently should I treat this

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to intialize area with a **String**
Try this :

```
area = SHAPE_area
```

Comment: area = SHAPE_area
NameError: name 'SHAPE_area' is not defined. I think this has to do with me calling a field within an attribute table and then trying to use that variable for arithmetic....

Comment: I thought you had the variable declared somewhere already. Well then go ahead and initialize it with a value. Maybe you should edit the status with more code for us to look at. I am not sure what an attribute table is.

Comment: @KMitzka, How are you retrieving `SHAPE_area` from your attribute table? In fact, ARE you retrieving `SHAPE_area` at all? Are you reading it from a file, or a database?

Comment: i set the workspace to the geodatabase i am using before declaring the variables. 
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/../PoliceData.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
patrolZone = "C:/Users/../PoliceData.gdb/PatrolZones"
graffitiIncidents = "C:/Users/../PoliceData.gdb/GraffitiIncidents"
incidentField = "INCIDENTS"
priorityField = "PRIORITY"
area = "SHAPE_area"
nameField = "NAME"
areaSQMI = area/2589988.11